# Full url to image transform

Tags: image-transforms

I'm trying to setup a page where the html will be copied into Mailchimp for a newsletter. The images need to have a full path url. How would I construct the code to provide this? So instead of "/images/something.jpg" it would be "http://domain.com/images/something.jpg".

```
{% set imageTransform = { width: 520, height: 240 } %}
{% for image in entry.headerPhoto %} 
 <img src="{{ image.getUrl(imageTransform) }}"  alt="{{ entry.title }}" style="display:block;" >   
{% endfor %}
```

If there is text inside rich text fields is there any way to output the full url to those images too?

Comment: Do your images currently not have a full url? Normal output should provide a full url.  Are you using a local source or a third party source for you images like AmazonS3? If you setup your assets source in the CP *(Settings > Assets > Sources)* you can set the URL Prefix which should prefix all your asset urls.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the Settings > Assets > Sources url fixed the problem globally. Thanks for the help, aran.